# How to prevent the entire FlatList from rerendering when only one value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx

I implemented a React Native FlatList, but whenever I push ***one*** element onto the FlatList Data, each child of the FlatList is Re-rendered ***twice***.

Is there any way to just render the ***new*** element instead of the entire FlatList?

I think it's caused by the fact that the date prop of the component that I render changes, which triggers a first re-render, and then since the FlatList as a whole depends on this.props.store.dates, the entire FlatList re-renders for a second time.

Here is how I implemented the FlatList:

```
@inject("store")
@observer
class Agenda extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={toJS(this.props.store.dates)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <DayInAgenda date={item} />}
        keyExtractor={(item) => { return item } }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how I implemented the Mobx store:

```
export default class Store {
  @observable dates = [
    "2019-05-10",
    "2020-05-17",
    "2021-05-18",
  ]

  @action addDate(date) {
    this.dates.push(date)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all I had to do was make DayInAgenda an observer.

Comment: You mean `DayInAgenda`? it had injectd properties?

Comment: observer? Please elaborate.